Azure Web App cannot find module '../server/require-hook'
Using Next.js to develop a web app.
Works perfectly with no errors with npm run dev and npm run build. (Both work with no errors on localhost)
Committed to github and it autodeploys on Azure Web App. However Azure keeps giving me this error below no matter what I do. Please help.
2024-10-10T22:01:42.094736390Z npm start
2024-10-10T22:01:53.765837254Z npm info using npm@10.7.0
2024-10-10T22:01:53.765888254Z npm info using node@v20.15.1
2024-10-10T22:01:58.629813469Z
2024-10-10T22:01:58.629881369Z > start
2024-10-10T22:01:58.629889169Z > next start -p $PORT
2024-10-10T22:01:58.629893669Z
2024-10-10T22:02:04.708839677Z node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148
2024-10-10T22:02:04.718146609Z   throw err;
2024-10-10T22:02:04.718164609Z   ^
2024-10-10T22:02:04.718168709Z
2024-10-10T22:02:04.718172409Z Error: Cannot find module '../server/require-hook'
2024-10-10T22:02:04.718186009Z Require stack:
2024-10-10T22:02:04.718190309Z - /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/next
2024-10-10T22:02:04.718194009Z     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15)
2024-10-10T22:02:04.718197909Z     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986:27)
2024-10-10T22:02:04.718201509Z     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:19)
2024-10-10T22:02:04.718205209Z     at Module.patchedRequire [as require] (/agents/nodejs/node_modules/diagnostic-channel/dist/src/patchRequire.js:16:46)
2024-10-10T22:02:04.718209109Z     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
2024-10-10T22:02:04.718212708Z     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/next:6:1)
2024-10-10T22:02:04.718217008Z     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1358:14)
2024-10-10T22:02:04.718220508Z     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)
2024-10-10T22:02:04.718224008Z     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32)
2024-10-10T22:02:04.718227508Z     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:12) {
2024-10-10T22:02:04.718231008Z   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2024-10-10T22:02:04.718234408Z   requireStack: [ '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/next' ]
2024-10-10T22:02:04.718238008Z }
2024-10-10T22:02:04.718241308Z
2024-10-10T22:02:04.718244808Z Node.js v20.15.1

Am running Node.js v20.15.1 and npm v10.7.0 locally - does not throw the same errors im seeing in Azure.

Are you deploying to Azure Web App on Linux or Windows?

If possible share your GitHub repository?

Add this start script "start": "node_modules/next/dist/bin/next start" to your package.json.

use this code while zip the files - name: Zip artifact for deployment.                                               run: zip release.zip ./* .next -qr in GitHub workflow file.

@alesha on Windows

@aslesha wow that worked!!! thank you!!

@Katsu Please check if the solution below helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.

I created sample nextjs app and deployed to Azure app service.

For deploying a Next.js app to an Azure Web App, I have added a start script to the package.json file.

"start": "node_modules/next/dist/bin/next start"


I added the below code to the GitHub workflow file.

- name: Zip artifact for deployment 
    run: zip release.zip ./* .next -qr

Below is my complete GitHub Workflow file.
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - kawebapp
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'
      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present
      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: release.zip
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: node-app
      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v2
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_CLIENTID_<key> }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_TENANTID_<key> }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_SUBSCRIPTIONID_<Key> }}
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3
        with:
          app-name: 'kawebapp'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .         

Azure App service Output:


@Katsu Is your issue resolved, let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.
